# Loopback/NodeJS app on AWS not responding consistently [Handshake inactivity timeout]

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeout, loopbackjs

I have deployed a Loopback 3 application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running Node 8.10. I consistently get failed request to the API, and when I checked the logs, I only see this:

```
Error: Handshake inactivity timeout
    at Handshake.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:164:17)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Handshake.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Handshake._onTimeout (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:129:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (/var/app/current/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:48:16)
    at MySQL.connect (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:89:17)
    at Object.initializeDataSource [as initialize] (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-connector-mysql/lib/mysql.js:43:28)
    at DataSource.setup (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:425:19)
    at new DataSource (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/datasource.js:123:8)
    at Registry.createDataSource (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback/lib/registry.js:362:12)
    at dataSourcesFromConfig (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:522:19)
    at Function.app.dataSource (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback/lib/application.js:229:14)
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:191:9
    at /var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:282:5
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at forEachKeyedObject (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:281:20)
    at setupDataSources (/var/app/current/node_modules/loopback-boot/lib/executor.js:181:3)
```

Weird thing is, I'm using postgresql. I used to have a mysql database but migrated to pg during development. The mysql datasource is still declared in `datasources.production.json` but it is not being used for any models. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Loopback attempts to connect to a datasources on startup, regardless of use by models

Comment: @icecream_hobbit I see. Makes sense I suppose. I'll remove that from the config. Thanks!